# Get past prompting/warning about .bash_profile entry to open VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

### Goal/resolution

Allow for opening code via `code .` while no longer getting prompted to edit `.bash_profile` every time I open VS Code

### Issue Details

When I open VS Code (insiders build) I am prompted with this message:

[image: Initial Message]

I click `Continue` and them am prompted with:

[image: Warning Message]

Then I click `Edit /[path]/.bash_profile`

Inside `.bash_profile` the only code related line is this:

```
function code () {
  VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders" --args "$@";
}
```

Which came directly from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/setup)

If I remove it the prompting goes away, but I am unable to open VS Code via terminal with `code .`

**Environment**

Mac OS X v10.10.5
VS Code v0.10.10-insider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the prompts were a little confusing but upon reading closer, I needed to remove it from `.bash_profile` completely. Then code added `code-insiders` to my path. Then to get the behavior I was looking for I added an alias to my profile: `alias code="code-insiders"`

Answer (score 2):

The command for the Insiders release is `code-insiders`, as indicated by the messages. This was done so you could still have the stable Code installed side by side and call it with `code`.

Comment: Right but that's just the name of the function, I wouldn't expect the name of the function to be pivotal for it to work. I will try this out and create an alias as I don't want to have to type out `code-insiders .` from the command line every time I launch (I don't use the non-insiders version)